# Is it possible to devirtualize this method call with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, clang, virtual

In the piece of code below, I expect the `a->f2()` call to be devirtualized, providing all compiler optimizations are enabled (`-O3`).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class AbstractA {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractA() = default;

    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2() {
        std::cout << "AbstractA::f2" << std::endl;
        this->f1();
    }
};

class ConcreteA final : public AbstractA {
    int x_;

public:
    /*void f2() override {
        this->f1();
    }*/

    void f1() override {
        std::cout << "ConcreteA::f1" << std::endl;
        x_++;
    }

    int get() const {
        return x_;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_unique<ConcreteA>();
    a->f2();
    return a->get();
}
```

While clang appears to deal with it properly by inlining subsequent method calls, yet GCC introduces a vtable and seems to use it later in the assembly ([see here](https://godbolt.org/z/sPPhq3Tfs)).

```
movq $vtable for ConcreteA+16, (%rax)
call AbstractA::f2()
...
movq 16(%rax), %rax
cmpq $ConcreteA::f1(), %rax
jne .L17
```

I am aware that the C++ standard does not enforce compilers to optimize by devirtualization. Nonetheless, my question is: is there anything that can be done so that GCC optimizes the call by omitting a vtable lookup?

Comment: Note that abstract base is no longer an abstract base since it contains an implementation.
If I do this : https://godbolt.org/z/Gf1x4sdd8 gcc will optimize the virtual call away. (I removed std::cout to remove a lot of the assembly blurb).

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- a class that has a pure virtual function is an abstract base class. Full stop. It doesn't matter whether it contains an implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class Yes you're right, in my mind all methods had to be pure virtual. So I learned something today :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- people often muddle C++'s notion of an abstract class with other languages' notion of an "interface".

Comment: Admittedly that's what I did. I use (non constructible/non copyable/non movable) abstract base classes with only pure virtual functions as interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that `AbstractA::f2` is not a pure member function, then you can simply override it explicitly from `ConcreteA` so GCC can inline `AbstractA::f2` and so `ConcreteA::f1`:

```cpp
    // In ConcreteA:

    void f2() override
    {
        AbstractA::f2();
    }
```

The vtable is still present due to a missing global optimization (GCC appears to consider that classes could possibly be used from outside while Clang know it is not the case, not to mention it better track pointers). [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) may help to fix that if this is a problem.

Theoretically, GCC has all the information here so to optimize the code without any modification but it does not due to missing optimization yet. Using Profile-Guided Optimizations (PGO) with Link-Time Optimizations (LTO) can help a lot to speculatively devirtualize member function calls (since GCC can know that there is no other classes using `AbstractA`, `ConcreteA` is only used in the `main`, better track pointers, etc.).